# Connecting to a remote IPython instance

Tags: python, ipython, zeromq, jupyter, pyzmq

I would like to run an IPython instance on one machine and connect to it (over LAN) from a different process (to run some python commands). I understand that it is possible with zmq : http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/ipythonzmq.html .

However, I can not find documentation on how to do it and whether it is even possible yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT

I would like to be able to connect to IPython kernel instance and send it python commands. However, this should not be done via a graphic tool (qtconsole) , but I want to be able to connect to that kernel instance from within a different python script...

e.g.

### external.py

```
somehow_connect_to_ipython_kernel_instance
instance.run_command("a=6")
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146558/connect-ipython-console-to-an-kernel-on-the-internet

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to run code in a kernel from another Python program, the easiest way is to connect a [BlockingKernelManager](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/zmq/blockingkernelmanager.py).  The best example of this right now is Paul Ivanov's [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) client, or IPython's own [terminal client](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/frontend/terminal/console/interactiveshell.py).

The gist:

- ipython kernels write JSON connection files, in `IPYTHONDIR/profile_<name>/security/kernel-<id>.json`, which contain information necessary for various clients to connect and execute code.
- KernelManagers are the objects that are used to communicate with kernels (execute code, receive results, etc.).
  *

A working example:

In a shell, do `ipython kernel` (or `ipython qtconsole`, if you want to share a kernel with an already running GUI):

```
$> ipython kernel
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-6759.json
```

This wrote the 'kernel-6759.json' file

Then you can run this Python snippet to connect a KernelManager, and run some code:

```
from IPython.lib.kernel import find_connection_file
from IPython.zmq.blockingkernelmanager import BlockingKernelManager

# this is a helper method for turning a fraction of a connection-file name
# into a full path.  If you already know the full path, you can just use that
cf = find_connection_file('6759')

km = BlockingKernelManager(connection_file=cf)
# load connection info and init communication
km.load_connection_file()
km.start_channels()

def run_cell(km, code):
    # now we can run code.  This is done on the shell channel
    shell = km.shell_channel
    print
    print "running:"
    print code

    # execution is immediate and async, returning a UUID
    msg_id = shell.execute(code)
    # get_msg can block for a reply
    reply = shell.get_msg()

    status = reply['content']['status']
    if status == 'ok':
        print 'succeeded!'
    elif status == 'error':
        print 'failed!'
        for line in reply['content']['traceback']:
            print line

run_cell(km, 'a=5')
run_cell(km, 'b=0')
run_cell(km, 'c=a/b')
```

The output of a run:

```
running:
a=5
succeeded!

running:
b=0
succeeded!

running:
c=a/b
failed!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/minrk/<ipython-input-11-fb3f79bd285b> in <module>()
----> 1 c=a/b

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

see the [message spec](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html) for more information on how to interpret the reply.  If relevant, stdout/err and display data will come over `km.iopub_channel`, and you can use the msg_id returned by `shell.execute()` to associate output with a given execution.

PS: I apologize for the quality of the documentation of these new features.  We have a lot of writing to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer! Exactly was I was looking for. Is it possible to receive the output of the command that ran in the kernel? e.g.: "a=2".."print a", and then receive "2"?

Comment: And is it possible to call IPython.frontend.terminal.embed.InteractiveShellEmbed() to open as kernel?

Comment: output comes over the iopub_channel.  As I linked above, the message spec details these messages, and vim-ipython and ipython console demonstrate how to deal with these messages.  As for the embed, I think you are asking for [this addition](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1357), which should be merged before long.

Comment: This worked great for me with IPython 2.2.0, I just needed to replace `BlockingKernelManager` with `IPython.kernel.blocking.client.BlockingKernelClient` and the same method calls work. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

If you just want to connect *interactively*, you can use SSH forwarding.  I didn't find this documented anywhere on Stack Overflow yet, yet this question comes closest.  This answer has been tested on Ipython 0.13.  I got the information from [this blog post](http://rsb.io/posts/ripkern-remote-ipython-kernels/).

1. Run `ipython kernel` on the remote machine:

   ```
   user@remote:~$ ipython3 kernel
   [IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
   [IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-25333.json
   ```
2. Look at the `kernel-25333.json` file:

   ```
   user@remote:~$ cat ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-25333.json 
   {
     "stdin_port": 54985, 
     "ip": "127.0.0.1", 
     "hb_port": 50266, 
     "key": "da9c7ae2-02aa-47d4-8e67-e6153eb15366", 
     "shell_port": 50378, 
     "iopub_port": 49981
   }
   ```
3. Set up port-forwarding on the local machine:

   ```
   user@local:~$ ssh user@remote -f -N -L 54985:127.0.0.1:54985
   user@local:~$ ssh user@remote -f -N -L 50266:127.0.0.1:50266
   user@local:~$ ssh user@remote -f -N -L 50378:127.0.0.1:50378
   user@local:~$ ssh user@remote -f -N -L 49981:127.0.0.1:49981
   ```
4. Copy the `kernel-25333.json` file to the local machine:

   ```
   user@local:~$ rsync -av user@remote:.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-25333.json ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-25333.json
   ```
5. Run ipython on the local machine using the new kernel:

   ```
   user@local:~$ ipython3 console --existing kernel-25333.json
   Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16)
   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   IPython 0.13.1.rc2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
   ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
   %quickref -> Quick reference.
   help      -> Python's own help system.
   object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.


   In [1]: import socket; print(socket.gethostname())
   remote
   ```

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know where the json file is located (like I didn't): it can be found by running `jupyter --runtime-dir`

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Note that the `-f` flag could be used to specify the path of the JSON file.

Answer (score 24):

Update to minrk's answer after the split to jupyter. With 
jupyter_client (4.1.1)
the simplest code is rather something like:

```
import jupyter_client

cf=jupyter_client.find_connection_file('6759')
km=jupyter_client.BlockingKernelClient(connection_file=cf)
km.load_connection_file()

km.execute('a=5')
```

Note that:

- jupyter_client.BlockingKernelClient is also aliased with jupyter_client.client.BlockingKernelClient.
- the shell (km.shell_channel) does not have the method execute() & get_msg() anymore.

Currently it is quite difficult to find an updated documentation; nothing yet on http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for BlockingKernelClient. Some code in https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_kernel_test. Any link welcome.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Man that's amazing! It is both extremely simple and efficient. I like it!

Comment: I'm in a JupyterLab notebook and two kernels are running. This code only connects to one of the kernels. How can I choose which one it connects to? Both have the same connection file.

Answer (score 7):

The above answers are a bit old. The solution for the latest version of `ipython` is much simpler but is not documented well at one place. So I thought I would document it here.

#### Solution to connect from any OS to a ipython kernel running on `Windows`

If either the client or server is a `linux` or other operating system, just change the location of `kernel-1234.json` appropriately based on [Where is kernel-1234.json located in Jupyter under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094744/what-is-the-jupyter-eqivalent-to-ipythons-find-connection-file)

1. On your windows based kernel start, make sure `ipykernel` is installed using `pip install ipykernel`
2. Start the `ipykernel` using `ipython kernel -f kernel-1234.json`
3. Locate the `kernel-1234.json` file on your `Windows` machine. The file will probably have a different number, not `1234` and will most likely be located in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-1234.json': https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332006/4752883
4. Install Jupyter Console (or Jupyter Qtconsole/notebook) using `pip install jupyter-console` or `pip install qtconsole` https://jupyter-console.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
5. If you are on Windows do a `ipconfig` to find out the ip address of your Windows server. (On Linux do a `ifconfig` at the shell prompt). In the `kernel-1234.json` file change the ip address from `127.0.0.1` to the ip address of your server. If you are connecting from another `Windows` server, then copy the `kernel-1234.json` file to your local computer and note down the path.
6. Navigate to the folder containing the `kernel-1234.json` and start *Jupyter Console* using `jupyter console --existing kernel-1234.json`

Comment: In my Windows installation, I don't have `ipykernel`, instead I have `jupyter-kernel`.  When this starts, it displays:  `Connection file: <path>\kernel-<guid>.json`.  In this file, it says `"ip": "127.0.0.1"`, so I don't see how using this file on the client machine could be used on the other machine trying to use this kernel?  When I change `127.0.0.1` to the IP address of the machine running `jupyter-kernel` (e.g. `10.0.0.122`) the Jupyter Console repeats `kernel died` every 3 seconds.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. When I wrote this, I was running the client and server on the same machine. In fact when you run Jupyter notebook, there is a client and a server which are running on the same machine, which is why `127.0.0.1` works fine. If you have to run your client and server on different machines, you need to 1. make sure that the server's ip is visible from the client. 2. in the kernel-1234.json, make sure to change the ip to whatever you client is set to.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the ip you mentioned `10.0.0.122` doesnt seem like a ip which would be visible from the client.  Did you try pinging your server with `ping 10.0.0.122` to check whether the server is visible from the client? and there is no firewall or something blocking the connection?

Comment: What have you intalled on your server and on your client?

Comment: Yes, the ping works.  Both machines are on the same LAN (`10.0.x.x` and `192.168.x.x` are common local LAN addresses).  The original question specifically asked about accessing IPython on a machine on the LAN.

Comment: Right now I am running the server and client in a Bridge Networking format so this does work on LAN connections. You will also notice there at multiple ports mentioned in the json file. Those ports need to be visible/open. Are you running any firewalls on your client and server?

Comment: Also I had a typo, in the above solution, if you are starting the `ipython kernel` you need to start it with the same `kernel-1234.json` file. The kernel-1234.json file should have the same ip address.

Comment: Can you try following the instructions using `ipykernel`, while using the file with the server ip and making sure there is no firewall running? When I do `pip list` on my server I don't see a `jupyter-kernel`. Also I don't see it listed as a kernel here: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels. When I try `pip install jupyter-kernel`, it doesn't install anything. So I am not sure what you are running..

Comment: Thanks, on the server, starting `ipython kernel --ip 10.0.1.122` (to explicitly specify its IP address) causes the .json file it creates to have that IP in it, instead of `127.0.0.1`), in addition it causes Windows Firewall to prompt to open the required ports.  Then, on the client machine, starting the client using that same .json file works.  It seems Python distributions are just starting to rename the IPython client parts to be Jupyter; my Anaconda dist had both.  When I started `ipython qtconsole` on the client it warned I should start using `jupyter qtconsole`.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Anaconda, in OS X the JSON file is stored at

> /Users/[username]/Library/Jupyter/runtime/

In Windows:

> c:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\

Comment: ... and c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\ on Windows

Comment: Does this answer the question? The OP wants to "*run an IPython instance on one machine and connect to it (over LAN) from a different process*".

Comment: @WaiHaLee, I think it does provide a crucial piece of solving the question. For a beginner, the location of the `kernel-1234.json` file can be confusing. For full solution with the latest version of ipython/ipykernel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332182/4752883