# Connect IPython Console to an kernel on the internet

Tags: python, ipython

I have been struggling to get this working. I have followed the online stuff I could find but have been unsuccessful e.g: [Ipython Documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/qtconsole.html)

I am trying to connect an IPython QTConsole on my local machine (laptop) to an IPython kernel running on a Linode cloud server on the internet.

I am not worried about security for now and just need the simplist way to do this.

I know I can start a kernel on the remote (Linode server ) using somethign like:

```
Ipython kernel --ip=0.0.0.0
```

Once i run this I can note down the kernel-xxxx.json file and I also know were to find it on the remote machine. Using the 0.0.0.0 notation I understand that the kernel will listen for outside connections.

I am just not sure how to connect to it from my local machine (Laptop)

Lets say

```
Remote machine  IP adres = aa.bb.cc.dd
Remote machine  Login name = root
Remote machine  hostname = dummyname
```

Local machine (Laptop)

```
 IPAdress = qq.ww.ee.rr
```

I can see the server and ssh to it normally e.g.

```
ssh root@aa.bb.cc.dd
```

**Can anybody please help me with the ipython command line to connect to this remote kernel from my laptop?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you have to know the IP address of your server (`ifconfig` on posix and `ipconfig` on windows). Lets say the IP address is `10.10.10.10`.

Then you can start the kernel on your server with:

```
ipython kernel --ip=* --IPKernelApp.connection_file=/tmp/kernel.json
```

When the kernel is started, get the content of the `/tmp/kernel.json`

```
$ cat /tmp/kernel.json
{
  "stdin_port": 59836,
  "ip": "*",
  "hb_port": 50806,
  "key": "11c2f53e-ad38-4d1d-b038-2f4bd04c4d49",
  "shell_port": 49904,
  "iopub_port": 55081
}
```

On your client create a `/path/to/your/kernel.json` file that has the same content, except that the ip address is the real ip address, and not the `*`:

```
{
  "stdin_port": 59836,
  "ip": "10.10.10.10",
  "hb_port": 50806,
  "key": "11c2f53e-ad38-4d1d-b038-2f4bd04c4d49",
  "shell_port": 49904,
  "iopub_port": 55081
}
```

After that you can start your `qtconsole` with:

```
ipython qtconsole --existing /path/to/your/kernel.json
```

You can connect as many `qtconsoles` as you want to the same kernel.

***Note:** Don't call the `exit()` function to exit your `qtconsole`, that will stop your kernel. Just click the close window button.*

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I have done this, and at least it tries to connect now. After a while though I get a message saying that the kernel did not respond. Should I open ports on the server or anything else?

Comment: Another question. Maybe this could be this issue. The local ipyton is 32 bit and the remote is 64 bit.... will it work to connect to the kernel under this configuration?

Comment: OK, i started up a 32 bit linode ubuntu instance...no luck trying to connect a 32 bit to 32 bit.... Keep ons stating that the kernel did not respond

Comment: No the python version shouldn't be a problem. Are the ports needed for kernel to work all open?

Comment: If you 1. can access the server with ping 2. all ports on the server are open 3. the kernel started and haven't reported any error. 4. both ipython-s (client and server) are the same version. 5. The json file on the server is identical (except the IP address) on the server and the client... I really cannot tell what the problem is. Can you at least connect from that server locally? Try `ipython console --existing /tmp/kernel.json` on the server from another session.

Comment: both sides running ipython 1  see this could be the problem    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3977

Comment: Haven't switched to 1.0 yet (it was released yesterday :D), so maybe some things are different. I still use 0.13.2.

Comment: just switched back to 0.13... Same old. I have double checked everything and same problem.Thanx for your help! will keep on trying to figure it out.

Comment: I am happy to report that I got this working using the description in the answer. I downgraded both sides to IPython 0.13, and also removed anaconda from both sides. Then it works. As soon as I am back at anaconda and or V1.00 of IPython things break again. So the instructions from Viktor is spot on. The only thing I realy changed was not to use --ip=* but --ip='0.0.0.0' with the quotes.