# Sending data from a web app to an ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

We have a web app that allows users to interactively discover web service data URLs.  We would like to allow a discovered service URL to be sent to an Ipython Notebook, where data from the service could be extracted, analyzed and visualized in the notebook.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic : [Connecting to a remote IPython instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977446/connecting-to-a-remote-ipython-instance?rq=1)

will show you how to execute python code from an app/script and return any "python objects" back to the notebook kernel.

Essentially what i will do in this case is to execute python code from the web app using the approach described before, note that for recent version of IPython (i use 3.0-dev) you should change :

```
from IPython.zmq.blockingkernelmanager import BlockingKernelManager
```

to :

```
from IPython.kernel import BlockingKernelClient
```

If your web-app can receive parameters in the url, you can construct the url+query from the notebook giving the connection info as one of the input parameters.
You can retrieve the connection ifo within the notebook using:

```
%connect_info
```

Comment: One note, in this scenario web-app and IPython notebook need to run on the same machine.

Comment: have a look a this notebook : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/epifanio/08f33dd8cea8d8564abf 
It shows how to connect flask with a running ipython notebook kernel and pass simple parameters to it. In the example flask generate a python dict based on imput from the url, the generated dict is then available in the ipython kernel.