# how to connect to the ipython-notebook server with python?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect to the ipython-notebook kernel with a simple python app, but I have no idea how to approach it. Also I could not find any example either.
I know I have to use the magic function:%connect_info to get the connection information, but I do not know how to use in the python app. Does anyone have any code snippet or tutorial on how to connect to the ipython kernel using python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to a remote IPython instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977446/connecting-to-a-remote-ipython-instance)