# Start a process on another computer on the network

Tags: python, linux, windows, automation, network-programming

I'm required to start a series of python scripts and/or other windows executables. Some of these require a Windows system, others require a Linux machine.

Currently there are designated machines to run the OS-dependent programs. So I know where I want to start which program.

Is there a way to start a python script (or a windows executable) from a python script, on the local network, on another computer (e.g. run `192.168.0.101:/dir/python_script_123.py`?

The script, which should then run various programs may then look something like this in *pseudo code*..

```
linuxip = 192.168.0.101
linuxparam = "required parameter"

winip = 192.168.0.201
winparam = "required parameter"

#option 1 (run all), 2(run linux only), 3(run windows only), 4(run local only)
option = 1

if option == 1:
    magic_things.run("linuxip:/dir/linux_script.py" + linuxparam)
    magic_things.run("winip:C:\\dir\\windows_prog.exe" + winparam)
    subprocess.call(["/dir/local_script.py","parameter"])
    subprocess.call(["/dir/another_local_script.py","parameter"])
elif option ==2:
    [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect to your server machine from your client. In case of the linux machine you could use SSH.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

Assuming you have a `ssh server` on the linux server running you could use the package paramiko (http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html) to connect to the machine and run your script there.

This could look something like this:

```
from paramiko.client import SSHClient

client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('linuxip', username='your_user', password='very_secret')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('python /home/your_user/your/path/to/scripty.py')
```

However please note that it's not very secure to store passwords in scripts and it's probably better to use a public/private key authentication (See the wiki article).

The paramiko package also offers the option for an ssh server, so this might be a solution for your windows machine, but I am not very sure as I don't run any windows machines any more.

Hope this was helpful!

David

Comment: A lnumber of options are listed in this post: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-control-a-computer-using-Python/answer/Jim-Dennis-1?srid=p2Po

Answer (score 1):

install `ipython` and `ipython kernel` on the remote server, and `ipython` and `ipython kernel` on the local machine. Then you can connect to the remote server using the settings here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332182/4752883

and run any program that would run on the remote machine using `subprocess` or the `os` builtin libraries. Further this is OS independent, so it will work whether your client/server is `linux` or `Windows` or `Mac`