# How to send commands to ipython console session

Tags: python, console, kernel, ipython, jupyter-console

How do IDEs like [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) send commands to their interactive ipython shell (such as `runfile()` when you click the run button)? Is there a way to open an ipython console and send commands to the kernel from outside the console (e.g. from a cmd or python script)?

I've read in the ipython documentation about messaging and the [`execute_request`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/2.x/development/messaging.html#execute) message type, but it gives no indication as to how you would implement that. And I'm not sure it's even what Spyder uses - in Spyder, when you click run, the `runfile()` command is inserted into the ipython console input.

Comment: maybe answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977446/connecting-to-a-remote-ipython-instance/35792945#35792945

i'm using this as a cli script here https://github.com/WillForan/wf-utils/blob/master/jpsnd