# Connect to remote python kernel from python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, papermill

I have been using [PaperMill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) for executing my python notebook periodically. To execute compute intensive notebook, I need to connect to remote kernel running in my EMR cluster.

In case of Jupyter notebook I can do that by starting jupyter server with `jupyter notebook --gateway-url=http://my-gateway-server:8888` and I am able to execute my code on remote kernel. But how do I let my local python code(through PaperMill) to use remote kernel? What changes do what to make in Kernel Manager to connect to remote kernel?

One related SO answer I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977446/connecting-to-a-remote-ipython-instance). This suggests to do port forwarding to remote server and initialize KernelManager with the connection file from the server. I am not able to do this as `blockingkernelmanager` is no longer in Ipython.zmp and I would also prefer HTTP connection like how jupyter does.

Answer (score 2):

**Hacky approach - Set up a shell script to do the following :**

1. Create a python environment on your EMR masternode using the `hadoop` user
2. Install [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) in your environment and configure all kernels as described in the README.md file for sparkmagic
3. Copy your notebook to master node/use it directly from s3 location
4. Run with papermill :

   papermill s3://path/to/notebook/input.ipynb s3://path/to/notebook/output.ipynb -p param=1

Step 1 and 2 are one time requirements if your cluster master node is the same every time.

**A slightly better approach :**

1. Set up a remote kernel in your Jupyter itself : [REMOTE KERNEL](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh)
2. Execute with papermill as a normal notebook by selecting this remote kernel

I am using both approaches for different use cases and they seem to work fine for now.