# How to see the Jupyter message being passed to the Jupyter Kernel?

Tags: jupyter

Is there a way to print the jupyter messages being passed to the Jupyter Kernel after executing a statement in a notebook? I'm not able to find anything online.

Answer (score 1):

There are some related discussions at the [Jupyter Discourse forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/):

- `requestExecute` and `onReply, etc. handler functions on the future, or listen to the future’s done promise` is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/kernel-requestexecute-content-error-exceptions-logging/1039)
- Listening to kernel messages in JupyterLab is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/check-for-cell-execution-completion-in-jupyterlab-extension/3083/5) and you may want to ask there about extensions mentioned that listen to kernel messages.
- I've seen `experimental_do_complete()` [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/d0ef2e40157c8a8f071818b074650a2f0b81f878/ipykernel/ipkernel.py#L371) referenced as being a way to add some logging to the ipykernel.
- `register_target() call` via `Comm` is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/frontent-to-kernel-callback/1666)
- more on `ipykernel` communicating via comms [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/race-condition-with-ipykernel-nbextension-comms/347)
- using `ZeroMQ` to access the kernel is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/kernel-communication-variables-workspace-view/924)
- Kernel Gateway providing an HTTP+WebSockets interface to kernel management and kernels is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/embedding-jupyter-ipython-in-a-client-server-application/2547)
- executing python code in the kernel on the user's behalf and dealing with how the output is returned, involving comms and API mention, is discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/better-way-to-communicate-from-kernel-from-to-jupyterlab-extension-than-prints/18100?u=fomightez).

On StackOverflow, I just noted:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977601/connect-to-remote-python-kernel-from-python-code/60094686#60094686) links to [a page](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh) that explains how to set up a kernel on a remote machine (server), and interact with the kernel on a local machine (client) via a qtconsole